# Visual Studio 2013 not starting unless file is selected to load

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, parallels

I am running VS 2013 ultimate on win 8.1  Parallels and everything was working fine, now does not.  I have repaired the install, and have even uninstalled and reinstalled VS 2013.  WHen I run devenv.exe the initial VS loading screen shows and just spins.  When I look at Task Manager, I only see VS running as a background process and eating up the CPU.

When I select a solution file or xml file as an example and choose the VS 2013, VS comes up and loads the file.  Any ideas of how to get this working would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the IDE to come up in safemode, so I figured it was one of the third party addins.  It seems like the Productivity Power Tools addin was the culprit in my situation.